# Cucumber 5.5.0 my step annotations (Before, After, BeforeStep...) do not work

Tags: java, cucumber

after upgrading to cucumber 5.5.0, and using io.cucumber.java imports instead of cucumber.api.java imports, any annotations I try no longer work. Everything except BeforeStep and AfterStep were working fine before upgrading.. the only reason I upgraded was so that I could use the BeforeStep and AfterStep annotations.

Here is my pom.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   
       <groupId>com.maven.cucumbertest</groupId>
       <artifactId>com.maven.cucumbertest</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   
       <properties>
           <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
           <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
       </properties>
   
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
               <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
               <version>5.5.0</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
               <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
               <version>3.141.59</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
               <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
               <version>2.7</version>
           </dependency>
           
       </dependencies>
   
   
   
   </project>
```

Here is my Runner class:

```js
package ggh.vcf.testRunner;     

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;        
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;        
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)                
@CucumberOptions(features="Features", glue={"ggh.vcf.stepDefinitions"}, monochrome=true, tags= {"~@SmokeTest, @RegressionTest"})                        
public class Runner                 
{       

}
```

Here is my (shortened) StepDefinitions class:

```js
package ggh.vcf.stepDefinitions;

import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.AfterStep;
import io.cucumber.java.BeforeStep;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;


public class Steps {

    WebDriver driver;

    private Scenario myScenario;

    @Before()
    public void embedScreenshotStep(Scenario scenario) {
        myScenario = scenario;
    }
    
    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep() {
        System.out.println("before step");
    }
    
    @AfterStep
    public void afterStep() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("after step");
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        
        if (driver != null & driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text(),'404 Error! Page Not Found']")).isDisplayed()) {
            System.out.println("in if statement");
            String fileName = "PageError_" + myScenario.getName() + "_"
                    + dateFormatter.format(currentDate).replaceAll(":", "-") + ".png";
            String filePath = "target/page-errors/";
            takeScreenshot(fileName, filePath);
        }
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) throws Throwable {
        myScenario = scenario;
        if (myScenario.isFailed()) {
            Date currentDate = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            String fileName = "Error_" + myScenario.getName() + "_"
                    + dateFormatter.format(currentDate).replaceAll(":", "-") + ".png";
            String filePath = "target/failed-tests/";
            takeScreenshotByUrl(fileName, filePath, "dashboard");
        }
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Given("^Open the Chrome browser and launch the application$")
    public void Open_the_Chrome_browser_and_launch_the_application() throws Throwable {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "REDACTED");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("REDACTED");
    }

    @When("^Enter the \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void enter_the_and(String username, String password) throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys(password);
    }

}
```

Seems like it's not registering any annotations as I get the "You can implement missing steps with the snippets below" message even though I have all methods and they were working before when I was using cucumber.api.java imports in my step definitions class.  Please help.

Comment: You still have the old imports in your runner class.

Comment: And you've just removed the info from your pom to ask the question. You've not actually Made your project simpler

Comment: If you don't make an MCVE no one can help you. If you do make the MCVE there is a good chance you don't need the help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example